# How to run "CREATE TABLE .. (col AS (select sql))" in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below script could run success:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (col1 INT, col2 AS col1 * 2) 
INSERT INTO T1  (col1)VALUES ( 7 )
SELECT * FROM T1 --Result: 7,14
```

[dbfiddle Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=577b81ee11313b791385d14a80a0ed55)

but if I hope `as select sql` then it'll get error, ex:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (col1 INT, col2 AS (select xxx from otherTable)) 
INSERT INTO T1  (col1)VALUES ( 7 )
SELECT * FROM T1 --Result: Error,Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

Are there any other equivalent methods in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the purpose of storing calculated column? Wouldn't be easier to create table with one column and query second in manner you showed us?

Comment: What's wrong with the first approach? Why do you want a select as the expression for the calculated column? That SELECT expression returns a constant value anyway, so I don't see the point in doing that to begin with.

Comment: because it's old system , i can't make a view , only could use column and it want to select from other table

Comment: You can't define a computed column that gets its value from another table; it can only use the column values of the current row. Something like that requires a view with a join, or an insert/update trigger, depending on the scenario.

Comment: you can define a computed column that selects from another table via a scalar UDF but this has multiple adverse performance issues. It forces row by row evaluation, prevents parallelism on the table, plus has the overhead of the UDF

Comment: thanks everyone, i'll make a sql scheduler  regularly update colmun.